# Place List<T> values in two arrays

Tags: c#, linq

I have the class:

```
public class DataModel {
  public int X { get; set; }
  public int Y { get; set; }
}
```

And the following list:

```
var data = new List<DataModel>();
data = service.GetData();
```

I need to change the List to a List:

```
public class NewDataModel {
  public int[] XValues { get; set; }
  public int[] YValues { get; set; }
}
```

So XValues are all the X Values in the original list ... The same with YValues.

How can I do this with Linq?

Thank You,
Miguel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are expected to post your best try.

```
var newList = new NewDataModel { 
                  XValues = data.Select(dm => dm.X).ToArray(), 
                  YValues = data.Select(dm => dm.Y).ToArray() };
```

Comment: Sorry, you are right .. In fact what your posted was what I tried but I was trying to avoid having the 2 selects because the original  DataModel might have many Y fields, eg, Y1, Y2, Y3, ... So I was figuring if Linq has some kind of command that would make this in one step or something like it ...

Comment: @MDMoura Once it's in memory the select should be cheap - it's little more than a for loop.  Are you really doing something where that's going to be a noticeable bottleneck?

Comment: Well, in fact I am taking this from a database using Entity Framework so I have an IQueryable ...

Comment: If you data is of type IEnumerable, you should materialize it by calling ToList or ToArray first before doing the two selects. That way, the actual execution will take place only once and the Selects will only be in memory.

Answer (score 2):

Untested, but something like this:

```
var newDataModel = new NewDataModel();
newDataModel.XValues = data.Select(d => d.X).ToArray();
newDataModel.YValues = data.Select(d => d.Y).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Aggregate` to loop it just once:

```
newDataModel = data.Select((x,i)=>new{ x, i})
                   .Aggregate(new NewDataModel(){XValues = new int[data.Count],
                                                 YValues = new int[data.Count]}, 
                              (a,b)=> {
                                a.XValues[b.i] = b.x.X;
                                a.YValues[b.i] = b.x.Y;
                                return a;
                             });
```